# Updated react-native and now it wont build

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So I have included an image of the console error as I have no clue what I've done wrong, when I updated react native every time I run yarn android to push the app to my emulator it fails with this error.

I'm guessing its something to do with the version of the appcompat being different to the packages but I am unsure of how to fix it.

I have tried to change my build.gradle to v7 26.1.0 but that didn't seem to work either.

[image: console error img]

Comment: did you upgrade your gradle version?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add images rather as images than as links. This time I've done this for you - please see [the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**: This is because one of your library use Gradle version of 26 to build android packages.

**Solution**:

Change `maven` in **android/build.gradle**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

and add these line in same file at end

```
subprojects {
   afterEvaluate { 
     project -> if (project.hasProperty("android")) { 
       android { 
        compileSdkVersion 26 buildToolsVersion '26.0.2' 
       } 
      }
    } 
}
```

Change `compilesdk and buildVersion`  in **android/app/build.gradle** as

```
compileSdkVersion 26 buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
```

and in **dependencies**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
}
```